# Console Log from Props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, react-hook-form

I'm confused as I have managed to get my data to be logged via different means, but confused as to why when I use props for the data (rather than repeating code) it will not log the input.

For reference, I have a field component that will take props to drive what my react-hook-form TextField will request. I'd like to expand on the component but until it logs my data, I cannot proceed!

Below is the code that actually logs my data:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core/";

const NewRequest = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name='firstName'
          render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref } }) => (
            <TextField
              label='First Name'
              variant='filled'
              size='small'
              onBlur={onBlur}
              onChange={onChange}
              checked={value}
              inputRef={ref}
            />
          )}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <Button type='submit' variant='contained'>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewRequest;
```

[image: Working code]

I have then moved the Controller, TextField to create a component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core/";

const TextFieldComponent = (props) => {
  const { name, label, size, variant } = props;
  const { control } = useForm();

  return (
    <div>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) => (
          <TextField
            label={label}
            variant={variant}
            size={size}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChange={onChange}
            checked={value}
            inputRef={ref}
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextFieldComponent;
```

Which I am using inside of another component (to generate a full form) and passing through my props (I will make a different component for Button, but for now it is where it is):

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import TextFieldComponent from "./form-components/text-field";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core/";

const NewRequest= () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TextFieldComponent
        name='firstName'
        label='First Name'
        size='small'
        variant='filled'
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Button type='submit' variant='contained'>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewRequest;
```

Now pushing that component into an index.js file to render a form:

```
import React from "react";
import NewVendorForm from "../components/new-vendor-request";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

const Home = () => {
  const { handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <NewVendorForm />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I'm stumped as to why this way would
a) customise my TextField in my form as intended
b) but not log my data as requested

[image: Not working code]

I'm sure there is a very valid, basic reason as to why and it is my lack of understanding of console logging, but am in need of help to resolve!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that, in the refactored code, you're calling `useForm` twice, each of which generates a different `control` and data.  You probably want to call `useForm` at the top level only, and pass in whatever you need (in particular `control`) to the form fields.

```js
const Home = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <NewVendorForm control={control} />
    </form>
  );
};

const NewRequest= ({control}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TextFieldComponent
        name='firstName'
        label='First Name'
        size='small'
        variant='filled'
        control={control}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Button type='submit' variant='contained'>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

const TextFieldComponent = (props) => {
  const { name, label, size, variant, control } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={name}
        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) => (
          <TextField
            label={label}
            variant={variant}
            size={size}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChange={onChange}
            checked={value}
            inputRef={ref}
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes sense.